# Compare date in date picker with current date

Tags: html, angularjs

```
<div class="input-group" ng-init="d.expiredAt = toDate(d.expiredAt);">

<input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="dd/MMM/yyyy"
is-open="popup1.opened" ng-required="false"
close-text="Close" ng-model="d.expiredAt" ng-readonly="!editing"/>
```

I want to compare this date with current date and highlight this field with red if it is < than current date.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the purpose of your feature is to notify / prevent user from selecting a date before today ?

If it's the case, the bootstrap-ui component you're using provides the feature :

> minDate (Default: null) - Defines the minimum available date.
>   Requires a Javascript Date object.

If you declare the today's date in your controller :

```
$scope.now = new Date();
```

You can use it like this in your HTML :

```
<input type="text" min-date="now" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="dd/MMM/yyyy"
  is-open="popup1.opened" ng-required="false"
  close-text="Close" ng-model="d.expiredAt" ng-readonly="!editing"/>
```

It will disable the selection of passed dates.

Comment: its like user have selected date after 2 days, but say you are accessing it after 3 days, so its expired. hence i want to highlight it, if its passed the current date

Comment: In this case it is more complicated, maybe a solution could be to override the template of the directive using template-url attribute of the directive.